# Addition on a prime factorization

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

This question is sort of in-between a computer science question and a math question.
Let's say I'm representing a very large number as a prime factorization in order to not break the limitations of a variable size.

ex)
n = 999,999,999 could be stored in an array as [3, 3, 3, 3, 37, 333667]

Is there a formula or technique that would allow me to perform addition on the prime factorization without converting the array back into it's whole number form?

n+1 = {number too large} = [?, ?, ?, ?, ?]

Comment: Not a known efficient one, since such an algorithm could allow efficient factorization (by adding 1 and multiplying by 2 many times). Additionally, note that a composite plus one could be a prime, so saving its factors doesn't let handle smaller numbers. You might be interested in CRT representation of numbers

Comment: In particular , we could factor the Fermat numbers and in particular determine whether they are prime.

Comment: Thanks, Command Master! I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to apply CRT to this context but I think this is exactly what I was looking for.